# Selenium - clicking on button is not recorded

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to test a web page using Selenium IDE. Am new to selenium.

The code is something like this.

```
<script src="type="text/javascript">
<script src="max.js" type="text/javascript">
<ul class="toolbar">
<li id="addTitle">
<span class="icon-add">Create New Title</span>
</li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

When I click on 'Create New Title' - Selenium does not record anything. Please let me know if I need to provide any further information.

Thanks!

I have tried 'View Xpath'.
But 'View XPath' shows

id('addTitle')/x:span

Results from https://abc.xyz.com/ui/states/LisitTitles.ddx

But I want to add
https://abc.xyz.com/ui/states//ManageStates.ddx?action=add
 which is for Create New Title button

I don't see https://abc.xyz.com/ui/states//ManageStates.ddx?action=add
anywhere in the page source code or Xpath.

In Page source I see:
document.location = ABC.PM.TITLE.builderURL + "?action=add";
Also how do I know whether it is Open/Click/etc commands I should be
using? Also does this have something to do with Pagination?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this manually by using xPath:

```
Command   |   click (or clickAndWait)
Target    |   //li[@id='addTitle']/span[@class='icon-add']
Value     |
```

It will cause clicking an element containing the text 'Create New Title', as you see.

Answer (score 3):

`Open` command is for openning a new web page.

`Click` command is for simulating a user clicking on an element.

On the selenium IDE window you can display all the available commands. You just have to click on the triangle above the "Find" button.

There is also a description for every command in the "Reference" tab

You can take a look on a screenshot here for more informations :
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#ide-features#opening-the-ide

Comment: thanks so basically i will have to see of all the commands which one will work for that action

Comment: I can also advise you to use typeKeys instead of type. There are a lot of little tricks like these so be patient with Selenium ;) it's a really powerful tool